# How to fix the white screen it appears after splash screen - react native

Tags: react-native

Im having a issue that white screen appears after splash screen loads and the app gets started .

I have already tried with some codes and using js and native but does't work

```
   componentwillmount{
 splashscreen.hide();
}
```

Comment: have you tried to use componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount?

Comment: yes i have tried but no response

Comment: Are you using any navigation libraries ?

Comment: yes we using navigation libraries

Answer (score 1):

In case of Android put android:windowDisablePreview into your styles.xml. 
I hope it will help you.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar_color</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

Please try the below code as well.

```
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      SplashScreen.hide()
    }, 300)
}
```

Comment: You can increase the timeout time according to your requirement.

Comment: was this helpful ?

Comment: I hope you will accept my answer. It will help others :)